# ¿Se puede que a partir del mensaje de firebase muestre determinado contenido en la app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

¿Se puede que a partir del mensaje de firebase muestre determinado contenido en la app?

```
package juegos.example.com.appwfb;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyFirebaseMessagingService fbb = new MyFirebaseMessagingService();
        fbb.onMessageReceived();
    }
}
```

En otra clase

```
package juegos.example.com.appwfb;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e("FIREBASE", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    public void onMessageReceived() {

    }
}
```

Comment: depende que accion quieras realizar

Comment: lo que quiero es que el mensaje que se muestra en la barra de notificaciones se vea reflejado como tipo histórico de las notificaciones que han llegado en el activity principal

Comment: como las notificaciones que se muestran en instagram en el corazon por ejemplo ? que dice quien te da like y quien te sigue ?

Comment: Algo así, pero en este caso no tendría botón alguno, si no que al abrir la aplicación, el activity principal mostrara ese listado

Comment: Son dos cosas distintas, por un lado las notificaciones y por otro lado tenes que maneja los eventos adentro de la app cuya notificacion hace trigger

Comment: ¿Algo que me recomiendes?

Comment: cual es la funcion que deseas realizar?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar te recomiendo que leas la [documentación de notificaciones push de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) ya que el planteo que estas haciendo es incorrecto. 
El servicio de mensajería no se inicializa manualmente desde un Activity sino que registra en el manifest para que tu aplicación pueda recibir mensajes incluso estando cerrada.

Una vez que estes recibiendo los mensajes push de Firebase es simplemente cuestión de mostrar una [Notificación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) con el mensaje que quieras.